# How to sync a folder to Ubuntu One cloud via command line?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, command-line, database, ubuntu-one-api

I'm writing a shell script to back up my databases and send that backups to my Ubuntu One cloud. Basically, it dumps the databases into a sql file named after current date, putting it in a folder under `/var/backups`.

I need to make this folder `/var/backups/whatever` syncronizable to Ubuntu One, and make it sync every time a new file is posted there, all by commandline. How can I do these?

Comment: Services provided by Ubuntu are **on-topic**: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [u1sdtool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/u1sdtool.1.html) - command line utility for controlling ubuntuone-syncdaemon

First hit on Google when I search for "Ubuntu one from command line". Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: I already googled and discovered u1sdtool, but it's manpage doesn't helped me to know how to mark a folder to sync with it. Also, seems to me that tool works with folders already created and marked to sync. So, how can I mark a folder to sync with u1sdtool?

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward to me, although I've never used it so I won't swear by that. Can't you just run it with `--list-folders` to see what folders are synced now, add more with `--create-folder` and so on?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu One will not sync folders outside your home folder, so you can't mark /var/backups as a synced folder. If that folder was under /home/yourusername then you could mark it as synced with u1sdtool --create-folder=/home/yourusername/backups and then anything put in it would automatically be synced without you needing to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a symbolic link to your "not in home" folder to a folder in your home.

from terminal

```
$ cd /home/USERNAME/ubuntuone
$ mkdir FOLDERTOSYNC
$ sudo ln -s /var/backups/ /home/USERNAME/FOLDERTOSYNCC
```

If I understand symbolic links basically you should see every file in `var/backup` in your newly created folder in ubuntuone shared directories and also ubuntuone should see those files aand sync them, yes? I'm not exactly sure how ubuntu one works and have jjust now begun usiing symlinks myself (used too typing  alot lol )but am now configuring it to  backup my `/mail/root` so I can use ubuntu one as a administration mail client.  I also have zoneminder which I eventually wish to backup any recorded motion detect events to `ubuntu one/dropbox/drive/me/live`

Comment: OR you can use Rsync or something similar to SYNC your "not-home" folder to the ubuntu one shared directory and let ubuntuone take it from there.  Syncing two internal folders rather than symlink or bind will result in two copies of the directory but should still work in theory. Also it'll will take more time to sync internally and then sync externally as opposed to just creating a symlink or binding/mounting.

Comment: actiually from what im reading it seems when setting up symlink ubuntu one gives problems.  Also ubuntu one (running under user credentials?)  needs to have write access to the folder your syncing which if you have a folder owned by root and are trying to sync with ONE it shouldn't work in theory.  YOU COULD however set up a cron-job or create a daemon that runs the command "cp" and just copys the source files to the desitnation at ONE shared.  again two copies of everything but when in ONE folder should take user ownership. Use "cp" Dont use "cp -a". Look up crontab file editing.

Answer (score -2):

After reading and reading which I LOOOVE  to do this link when followed correctly will allow you to sync internally whatever folder to your home ubuntu one shared folder and from there it will sync.

```
rsync -a /source /destination
```

If you want to maintain ownership/permissions/privileges/attributes (`-a`) OR

```
rsync /source /dest
```

You might need to do it as root if your source is owned by root.

source of info: https://serverfault.com/questions/259938/cron-job-to-copy-file-from-one-location-to-another-for-new-files-daily

Comment: I don't think this provides an answer to the question.